# Is it possible to measure how much time OpenGL takes transfering data to the GPU?

Tags: c++, opengl

I think I have a few questions under the title's topic.

1. If I have a (CPU-side) staging buffer `glMapBufferRange`'d to a buffer (`SSBO`, or otherwise), are there any `gl...` calls I can make to force the *actual* (CPU -> GPU) upload happen in a way in which I can use `glBeginQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED, ...)` to measure how long it takes to upload the data?
2. What about if I make use of some of the workflows associated with `glMapBufferRange`'s flags (`GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT`, `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT`, `GL_MAP_FLUSH_EXPLICIT_BIT`, `GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT` )?
3. If `1.` and `2.` are not possible, is there any way (OpenGL or otherwise) of measuring how long it takes to upload to a GPU in a C++ OpenGL application?

Comment: Which gpu? You'll likely need to use the manufacturer's profiling tools

Comment: NVidia - and fair enough.

Comment: 1 Opengl operations are often asynchronous which makes hard to measure elapsed time. glFinish can be used to synchronize CPU and GPU before making a measurement. However, remember that glFinish is a blocking call and it may affect the performance.